# How many RDDs in cache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application which cache RDDs at runtime based on datasets and perform operation.

For monitoring purpose I want to find out the number of RDDs in cache when application is running, does Spark provides any APIs to find out this details?

Comment: @zero323. this solution only would work when i want to fetch cache rdd in same application. but i want to find out cache RDDs in separate program/application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use [Spark REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) which provides two endpoints:

- `/applications/[app-id]/storage/rdd`  - list of all stored RDDs.
- `/applications/[app-id]/storage/rdd/[rdd-id]` - detail information for particular RDD.

Comment: it works in my local dev environment.But in my gold/platinum environments the spark history server is installed for yarn :( is there any other alternative?